# Create idea project using gen-idea

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-idea

I'm new to the `sbt` and `scala`. I've installed `sbt` and `sbt-idea`. How can I create an idea project now ?

Comment: RTFM? https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea#basic-project. BTW Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA 13 has built-in sbt support.

Comment: I've done those steps. but gen-idea command is not valid yet. why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally got it work fairly painlessly by following the documentation: add the following lines to your project's `./project/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

Reload `sbt`, the `gen-idea` command should now be available.